# how does ORDER BY take precedence?

Tags: mysql

So I have a table where I add some data:

```
id - name - year - joined
1    Bob    1980   0
2    John   1970   0
3    Jack   1975   2
4    Kate   1990   1
```

column joined is the `id` number

I'd like to list it like this

```
Bob
 Kate
John
 Jack
```

so Kate joined Bob and Jack joined John

my select query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY `id DESC`, joined DESC";
```

but it lists it by id and that takes the precedence. Is there a way to do it so joined is treated as `id` in instance where joined doesn't equal `0`

Comment: RTM http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/order-by-optimization.html and you have a syntax error. Unless you fat-fingered that.

Comment: order works in the order you specify the clauses: `order by a,b,c`. `a` records get sorted first. then for every `a` record with the same value, the `b` values get sorted, and for all records with the same `b` value, the `c` records get sorted. what you want would probably be accomplished with `order by joined=0, id, joined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an expression in the order by to give you you the right order:

```
order by if(joined=0,id,joined), id
```

Comment: perfect! Remove ,id and I will give you correct answer

Comment: I would retain the id because you will see the persons joined by the same person in the order of them joining.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a pairing ,go for self join as given

```
SELECT CONCAT(A.name,'-',B.name)
FROM table_name A
  INNER JOIN table_name B ON A.id = B.joined
```

hope this helps..